# Word count list unable to rename column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this code that reads the column 'NAME' and returns a word occurrence of each word.

```
temp_df = pd.read_excel('file location here', index=True)

final_df = pd.Series(' '.join([unicode(i) for i in temp_df.NAME]).split()).value_counts()
```

The problem is the first column which is the name of the word always becomes the index by default even if i do something like

```
final_df.rename({0: 'word', 1: 'count'})
```

It will tell me that exist only 1 element but i'm trying to rename 2 elements but the reason is because it treats the 'word' column as the Index, any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output is `Series`, so need [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
final_df = final_df.reset_index()
final_df.columns = ['word', 'count']
```

Another solution:

```
final_df = final_df.reset_index(name='count').rename(columns={'index':'word'})
```